# What does git-quiltimport do?

Tags: git

What does the new git command `git-quiltimport` actually do? From the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-quiltimport)

> git-quiltimport - Applies a quilt patchset onto the current branch
>
> Applies a quilt patchset onto the current Git branch, preserving the
>   patch boundaries, patch order, and patch descriptions present in the
>   quilt patchset.

This description is not clear to me. What is the `quilt patch` concept in git and  what does `git-quiltimport` actually do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git quiltimport` (note that you don't need the dash, and this is true for all `git-foo` commands) seems to apply a series of patches stored in a specific format (a quilt patchset, see below).

I would expect it to behave similarly to several `git am` which applies one or several patches from e-mails stored in the [maildir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir) format (or from a single e-mail file).

The rest of this answer is copied from [What is a quilt patchset?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/766759/324969) .

> Quilt is a [patch managing tool](http://mybravenewworld.wordpress.com/2007/11/13/quilt-patch-management/). The idea is that it makes it easier for you to maintain multiple, discrete sets of changes in a single source client, even if they touch the same files.
>
> The [official site](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/quilt) is sparse on details, but worth if you are thinking of using it.
>
> If you didn't use quilt, you would probably just have to create another client to maintain the separate change sets, but you would have to patch back and forth changes that would benefit both client source trees.